# How can I start the angular app with this gulp script?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, meanjs

I took a gulpfile from this location https://github.com/meanjs/mean. My version looks like this, I used a slightly moderated version just to run a dev version:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var _ = require('lodash'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    defaultAssets = require('./config/default'),
    glob = require('glob'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    gulpLoadPlugins = require('gulp-load-plugins'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    plugins = gulpLoadPlugins({
        rename: {
            'gulp-angular-templatecache': 'templateCache'
        }
    }),

    path = require('path'),
    endOfLine = require('os').EOL;


// Local settings
var changedTestFiles = [];


// Set NODE_ENV to 'development'
gulp.task('env:dev', function () {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
});


// Nodemon task
gulp.task('nodemon', function () {
    return plugins.nodemon({
        script: 'server.js',
        nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
        ext: 'js,html',
        watch: _.union(defaultAssets.server.views, defaultAssets.server.allJS, defaultAssets.server.config)
    });
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    // Start livereload
    plugins.livereload.listen();

    // Add watch rules
    gulp.watch(defaultAssets.server.views).on('change', plugins.livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch(defaultAssets.server.allJS, ['eslint']).on('change', plugins.livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch(defaultAssets.client.js, ['eslint']).on('change', plugins.livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch(defaultAssets.client.css, ['csslint']).on('change', plugins.livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch(defaultAssets.client.sass, ['sass', 'csslint']).on('change', plugins.livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch(defaultAssets.client.less, ['less', 'csslint']).on('change', plugins.livereload.changed);

    gulp.watch(defaultAssets.server.gulpConfig, ['eslint']);
    gulp.watch(defaultAssets.client.views).on('change', plugins.livereload.changed);
    // }
});


// Run the project in development mode
gulp.task('default', function (done) {
    runSequence('env:dev', ['watch', 'nodemon'], done);
});
```

I got the server working fine but there is nothing showing up on localhost:3000? How can i fix this?

Comment: do you have any errors? check your browser developer tools..

Comment: did you see any console.error on browser

Comment: No chrome just says: 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.